# Download pdf from High Charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am showing high chart in popup,when i download this chart its text getting cut.
I tried by giving padding and by decreasing font size also,but still its getting cut.
For better understanding i am attaching screen shot of popup and pdf.
[image: popup]

[image: pdf]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. If there are any references for this kind of issue, please let me know them also.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to set [exporting width](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/width/) to the necessary value.

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }],

        exporting: {
            width: 200
        }

    });
});​
```